# InvalidArgumentError: indices[] = is not in: Re-training not commencing after INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently fine tuning an ssd mobilenet v2 model to improve the human detection and receive the following issues:

```
2018-09-07 14:05:33.501707: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1471] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-07 14:05:34.037588: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:952] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-07 14:05:34.040906: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:958]      0
2018-09-07 14:05:34.043348: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   N
2018-09-07 14:05:34.045821: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4734 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from D:/Databases/Coco/cctv/tf/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from D:/Databases/Coco/cctv/tf/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model2/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model2/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, indices[1] = 2 is not in [0, 1)
         [[Node: cond_2/RandomCropImage/PruneCompleteleyOutsideWindow/Gather/GatherV2_1 = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT64, Tparams=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](cond_2/Switch_3:1, cond_2/RandomCropImage/PruneCompleteleyOutsideWindow/Reshape, cond_2/RandomCropImage/PruneNonOverlappingBoxes/Gather/GatherV2/axis)]]
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, indices[1] = 2 is not in [0, 1)
         [[Node: cond_2/RandomCropImage/PruneCompleteleyOutsideWindow/Gather/GatherV2_1 = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT64, Tparams=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](cond_2/Switch_3:1, cond_2/RandomCropImage/PruneCompleteleyOutsideWindow/Reshape, cond_2/RandomCropImage/PruneNonOverlappingBoxes/Gather/GatherV2/axis)]]
INFO:tensorflow:Caught OutOfRangeError. Stopping Training. FIFOQueue '_3_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
         [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2[component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](prefetch_queue)]]
```

It seems like there is a problem with reading the tf records since I do not receive the expected training summary shown in tutorial 2 after the INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec:0.

I have found many issues regarding this and commonly the solution is that the path may be incorrect to the tf record or the tf record is empty. In my case the path is correct and my tf records is 55000KB.

I am using the tutorial [tutorial 1](https://tech.3si.vn/2018/07/19/how-to-train-your-custom-object-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api/) and and referring to [tutorial 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/esmsdn/2018/04/09/post-invitado-part2-step-by-step-how-to-training-your-own-detector-classifier/). My images are 300 by 300 and I have 1 class.

My code to generate the tf records is as follows:

```
import os
import io
import glob
import hashlib
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import sys
sys.path.append("{D:\\Databases\\Coco\\cctv\\object_detection")
sys.path.append("D:\\Databases\\Coco\\cctv\\object_detection\\utils")
from PIL import Image
#import Image
import dataset_util #from object_detection.utils

'''
this script automatically divides dataset into training and evaluation (10% for evaluation)
this scripts also shuffles the dataset before converting it into tfrecords
if u have different structure of dataset (rather than pascal VOC ) u need to change
the paths and names input directories(images and annotation) and output tfrecords names.
(note: this script can be enhanced to use flags instead of changing parameters on code).
default expected directories tree:
dataset- 
   -JPEGImages
   -Annotations
    dataset_to_tfrecord.py   
to run this script:
$ python dataset_to_tfrecord.py 
'''
def create_example(xml_file):
        #process the xml file
        xmlp = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file,parser=xmlp)  
        #tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()       
        image_name =str(xml_file).rsplit('\\', 1)[-1].replace('.xml', '.jpg')[:-1]
        print("image_name",image_name)
        file_name = image_name.encode('utf8')
        size=root.find('size')
        width = int(size[0].text)
        height = int(size[1].text)

        xmin = []
        ymin = []
        xmax = []
        ymax = []
        classes = []
        classes_text = []
        for x_min in root.findall(".//xmin"):
            xmin.append(float(x_min.text) / float(width))            
        for y_min in root.findall(".//ymin"):
            ymin.append(float(y_min.text) / float(height))
        for y_max in root.findall(".//ymax"):
            ymax.append(float(y_max.text) / float(height))
        for x_max in root.findall(".//xmax"):
            xmax.append(float(x_max.text)/ float(width)) 

           #if you have more than one classes in dataset you can change the next line
           #to read the class from the xml file and change the class label into its 
           #corresponding integer number, u can use next function structure
        classes.append(1)   # i wrote 1 because i have only one class(person)
        classes_text.append('pedestrian'.encode('utf8'))

        #read corresponding image
        full_path = 'C:/Users/SDy/Desktop/testfinalALL/'+image_name  #provide the path of images directory     
        with tf.gfile.GFile(full_path, 'rb') as fid:
            encoded_jpg = fid.read()          
        encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
        image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
        if image.format != 'JPEG':
           raise ValueError('Image format not JPEG')
        key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_jpg).hexdigest()

        #create TFRecord Example
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
            'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
            'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(file_name),
            'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(file_name),
            'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
            'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
            'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
            'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmin),
            'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmax),
            'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymin),
            'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymax),
            'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
            'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),

        })) 

        print(example)
        return example  

def main(_):
    writer_train = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('C:/Users/SD/Desktop/tfrecordfinalALL/test2.record')     
    #writer_test = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('test.record')
    #provide the path to annotation xml files directory
    filename_list=tf.train.match_filenames_once('C:/Users/SD/Desktop/testxmlfinalALL/*.xml')
    init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess=tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)
    list=sess.run(filename_list)
    random.shuffle(list)   #shuffle files list
    i=1 
    trn=0   #to count number of images for training
    for xml_file in list:
      print(xml_file)
      print("                   jjj")
      print(i)
      example = create_example(xml_file)
      writer_train.write(example.SerializeToString())
      trn=trn+1
      i=i+1

    #writer_test.close()
    writer_train.close()
    print('Successfully converted dataset to TFRecord.')
    print('training dataset: # ')
    print(trn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

On completion,I move the tf records to the training folder and the path is defined in the config file.

[image: tfrecordpath].
My ssd_mobilenet model resides as shown in image.

[image]

My training path to my config file is shown in the image.

[image: config path]

My ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_config code is:

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 3
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      use_depthwise: true
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 24
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "D:/Databases/Coco/cctv/tf/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/tfrecordfinalALL/train2.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/tfrecordfinalALL/test2.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

My label_map.pbtxt contains the following:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'pedestrian'
}
```

Lastly to run the model on cmd prompt I use the following code:

```
(tensorflow) c:\models-master\research>python object_detection/legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/model2/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_2.config
```

Based on the information provide why is the issue occuring. It is not training or not opening the tf records. In addition to this the model is generated and when I test the model, I get the results below.

[image: outputfrommodel]

Comment: I corrected this by first creating csv from the xml and then the tf records. It worked fine thereafter.